# Custom property for people profiles

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, display-template

I have added 1 new property to people profile named "DepartementTest" and filled it out foreach user. I have added my new property to my custom display template. I have built a people-dictonary and added my new property to my template. My custom property dont display any text, what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a crawl and have to add your custom property in the managed metedata properties settings in the display template to get the data